# Multiple level @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes

Tags: java, jackson

I have class hierarchy A <- B <- C. I don't want class A to be aware of C, so I intend to use A.type="B" to indicate it to be class B, and then B.type2="C" to indicate it to be class C.

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B.class, name = "B")})
public abstract class A {

    private final String type;

    public A(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type2")
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = C.class, name = "C")})
public class B extends A {

    private final String type2;

    private final String propertyB;

    @JsonCreator
    public B(@JsonProperty("type2") String type2,
             @JsonProperty("propertyB") String propertyB) {
        super("B");
        this.type2 = type2;
        this.propertyB = propertyB;
    }
}

public class C extends B {

    private final String propertyC;

    @JsonCreator
    public C(@JsonProperty("propertyB") String propertyB,
             @JsonProperty("propertyC") String propertyC) {
        super("C", propertyB);
        this.propertyC = propertyC;
    }
}
```

When I read JSON of C to class A, the actual Java object is class B but not C.

```
@Test
void whenReadCJsonToA_thenObjectIsInstanceOfC() throws JsonProcessingException {

    String json = "{\n" +
                  "  \"type\" : \"B\",\n" +
                  "  \"type2\" : \"C\",\n" +
                  "  \"propertyB\" : \"b\",\n" +
                  "  \"propertyC\" : \"c\"\n" +
                  "}";

    A obj = objectMapper.readValue(json, A.class);
    assertTrue(obj instanceof B, "obj is not instance of B");  // pass
    assertTrue(obj instanceof C, "obj is not instance of C");  // fail
}
```

One way to make above test pass is [writing custom deserializer](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/cascade-JsonTypeInfo/tree/custom-deserializer), but this solution is tedious if the class holds many fields.

Is it possible to make above test pass with a more elegant way? Is my indention to cascade @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes completely wrong?

My maven project can be found in [Github](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/cascade-JsonTypeInfo).

Comment: I think the problem is in the constructor for class B when it calls super("B"), so the type in class A is always B.

Comment: @VladimirStanciu If B constructor parameters includes A.type, `B(@JsonProperty("type") String type, @JsonProperty("type2") String type2, @JsonProperty("propertyB") String propertyB) { super(type); this.type2 = type2; this.propertyB = propertyB; }`, the test still fails. When Jackson sees JSON property `type="B"`, Jackson uses constructor, in such case, the argument `type` is always "B". So it's the same as I hard code `super("B")` in B constructor. See branch [constructor-include-subtype-info](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/cascade-JsonTypeInfo/tree/constructor-include-subtype-info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Jackson issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/374), multiple level inheritance is supported with only one type discliminator property. In my code, keep only property `type` and remove property `type2`.

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B.class, name = "B")})
public abstract class A {

    private final String type;

    public A(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}

@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = C.class, name = "C")})
public class B extends A {

    private final String propertyB;

    @JsonCreator
    public B(@JsonProperty("propertyB") String propertyB) {
        super("B");
        this.propertyB = propertyB;
    }
}

public class C extends B {

    private final String propertyC;

    @JsonCreator
    public C(@JsonProperty("propertyB") String propertyB,
             @JsonProperty("propertyC") String propertyC) {
        super(propertyB);
        this.propertyC = propertyC;
    }
}
```

See full code in [this commit](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/cascade-JsonTypeInfo/commit/97719ad18b2bd8497745f679fcfb2452b20591b6).

[This commit](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/cascade-JsonTypeInfo/commit/b4ce18d27ff1c526e610ffe907883c255fa45e82) uses enum as type discliminator property type.